# Recreating facebooks help center sidebar navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

When viewing the [Facebook help center](https://www.facebook.com/help) on a desktop you can see that it has a [sidebar on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujZqi.png). If you click on one of the categories it will take you to a sub category or the topic id.

I am not looking for the way it shows and gets the topic urls, I am only looking for the css/javascript for that menu to work the way it shows the category to sub category or topic transaction.

If somebody could give me some tips on recreating or help me recreate I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an quick example and here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/7rsrN/)**</kbd>

```
<nav id="navigation">

  <ul class="main">

    <li class="withsub"><span class="toggle">Link</span>
      <ul class="sub">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="withsub"><span class="toggle">Link</span>
      <ul class="sub">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="withsub"><span class="toggle">Link</span>
      <ul class="sub">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>

  </ul>

</nav>
```

---

```
#navigation {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#navigation li {
  width: 236px;
  height: 36px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #6f7bbf;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
}
#navigation li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#navigation li:hover,
#navigation li a:hover {
  background: #ebeef4;
}
.sub {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
}
```

---

```
(function($) {
  $('.sub li:last-child').after('<li class="back">Back</li>');

  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('.main').animate({ marginLeft: '-250px' }, 400);
    $(this).next('.sub').animate({ left: '0' }, 400).css({ display: 'block' });
  });

  $('.back').click(function() {
    $('.main').animate({ marginLeft: '0' }, 400);
    $('.sub').animate({ left: '250px' }).fadeOut(400);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I know it's an old thread but how would I go about it being width 100%? not 250px?

Answer (score 0):

[Multi Level Push Menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/) over at Tympanus is a good example.

Though, limited to browser support, polyfill can assist.